# MassTransit with RabbitMQ unable to send message

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

Here is my MassTransmit MQ code, its config data and version details. Code is not moving further, neither it is proceeding not it is throwing any error. Unable to understand why, Since 4 days I am struggling to understand what is missing.

C# code
[image: Actual code]

For config file, please check screen shot
[image: Config file]

- Version details

C# 7.0
.Net core
MassTransit & RabbitMQ latest versions

I would be very thankful if you update what is missing so as why it is not proceeding.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure you are [following the documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration) - your configuration isn't correct.